# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR will not match the dot character

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I'm trying to extract information from strings like:

```
FOO-BAR-AUDIT-DATABASE.NUPKG
FOO.BAR.DATABASE-2.0.0.NUPKG
```

to info like:

```
'FOO.BAR.DATABASE' '2.0.0'
        |             |
   module_name     version
```

Currently I'm not able to parse correctly when the *module_name* part contains `.` chars. See table below.

The example below show how I extract the information.
The first group of the regexp is the one that do not work correctly `'(.*?)`, the remaining groups handle the cases of varying version information.

```sql
select case module_name when expected then 'pass' else 'fail' end as test, y.* from(
select lower(regexp_substr(t.pck, g.regex, 1, 1, '', 1)) as module_name, 
       t.expected,
       to_number(regexp_substr(t.pck, g.regex, 1, 1, '', 3)) as major,
       to_number(regexp_substr(t.pck, g.regex, 1, 1, '', 5)) as minor,
       to_number(regexp_substr(t.pck, g.regex, 1, 1, '', 7)) as patch,
       (t.pck) as package_name
from   (select 'FUNKY_LOG_DATABASE-1.0.0.NUPKG' as pck, 'funky_log_database' as expected from dual
        union select 'FOO.BAR.DATABASE-2.0.0.NUPKG', 'foo.bar.database' from dual 
        union select 'FOO-BAR-AUDIT-DATABASE.NUPKG', 'foo-bar-audit-database' from dual
        union select 'funk-database-1.nupkg', 'funk-database' from dual
        union select 'funk-database-1.2.nupkg', 'funk-database' from dual
        union select 'baz-database-1.0.1.nupkg', 'baz-database' from dual) t
cross  join (select '(.*?)(-(\d+)(\.(\d+))?(\.(\d+))?)?(\..*)' as regex from dual) g
)y;
```

The query above yields the following (Oracle 19c):

| test | module_name | expected | major | minor | patch | package_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pass | foo-bar-audit-database | foo-bar-audit-database |  |  |  | FOO-BAR-AUDIT-DATABASE.NUPKG |
| **fail** | foo | foo.bar.database |  |  |  | FOO.BAR.DATABASE-2.0.0.NUPKG |
| pass | funky_log_database | funky_log_database | 1 | 0 | 0 | FUNKY_LOG_DATABASE-1.0.0.NUPKG |
| pass | baz-database | baz-database | 1 | 0 | 1 | baz-database-1.0.1.nupkg |
| pass | funk-database | funk-database | 1 | 2 |  | funk-database-1.2.nupkg |
| pass | funk-database | funk-database | 1 |  |  | funk-database-1.nupkg |

I've tried use `([[:alnum:]._-]*?)` as the first group, but it yield the same result. Switching to a *greedy* match matches too much.

Any good suggestions out there?

Comment: This regexp `'^(.*?)(-(\d+)(\.(\d+))?(\.(\d+))?)?(\.[^.]+)$'` seems to work with your original code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match from the end to get the version then extract the sub-string before the version to get the module name:

```sql
select case module_name when expected then 'pass' else 'fail' end as test,
       y.*
from   (
  select lower(
           substr(
             t.pck,
             1,
             REGEXP_INSTR(t.pck, g.regex) - 1
           )
         ) as module_name, 
         t.expected,
         to_number(regexp_substr(t.pck, g.regex, 1, 1, '', 2)) as major,
         to_number(regexp_substr(t.pck, g.regex, 1, 1, '', 3)) as minor,
         to_number(regexp_substr(t.pck, g.regex, 1, 1, '', 4)) as patch,
         t.pck as package_name
  from   (
    select 'FUNKY_LOG_DATABASE-1.0.0.NUPKG' as pck, 'funky_log_database' as expected from dual
    union select 'FOO.BAR.DATABASE-2.0.0.NUPKG', 'foo.bar.database' from dual 
    union select 'FOO-BAR-AUDIT-DATABASE.NUPKG', 'foo-bar-audit-database' from dual
    union select 'funk-database-1.nupkg', 'funk-database' from dual
    union select 'funk-database-1.2.nupkg', 'funk-database' from dual
    union select 'baz-database-1.0.1.nupkg', 'baz-database' from dual
  ) t
  cross  join (
    select '(-(\d+)\.?(\d+)?\.?(\d+)?)?\.[^.]+$' as regex from dual
  ) g
)y;
```

Outputs:

> | TEST | MODULE_NAME | EXPECTED | MAJOR | MINOR | PATCH | PACKAGE_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | pass | foo-bar-audit-database | foo-bar-audit-database |  |  |  | FOO-BAR-AUDIT-DATABASE.NUPKG |
> | pass | foo.bar.database | foo.bar.database | 2 | 0 | 0 | FOO.BAR.DATABASE-2.0.0.NUPKG |
> | pass | funky_log_database | funky_log_database | 1 | 0 | 0 | FUNKY_LOG_DATABASE-1.0.0.NUPKG |
> | pass | baz-database | baz-database | 1 | 0 | 1 | baz-database-1.0.1.nupkg |
> | pass | funk-database | funk-database | 1 | 2 |  | funk-database-1.2.nupkg |
> | pass | funk-database | funk-database | 1 |  |  | funk-database-1.nupkg |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fea5913e6ee359d8935031200386752d)*

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of matching from the other side. I think this will work!

Answer (score 1):

Would this do? It isn't *sophisticated*, but - returns data you wanted (at least, I think so).

- lines #1 - 8 - sample data
- `temp` CTE: removes extension (.nupkg), for simplicity
- final query:

  - line #18 is `module name`; if it contains numbers, then get substring up to the first digit. Otherwise, remove the whole PCT value
  - lines #20 - 22 return `version`: if there are no digits, return NULL. Otherwise, return substring from the first digit onwards

---

```
SQL> with
  2  test as
  3   (select 'FUNKY_LOG_DATABASE-1.0.0.NUPKG' as pck, 'funky_log_database' as expected from dual
  4          union select 'FOO.BAR.DATABASE-2.0.0.NUPKG', 'foo.bar.database' from dual
  5          union select 'FOO-BAR-AUDIT-DATABASE.NUPKG', 'foo-bar-audit-database' from dual
  6          union select 'funk-database-1.nupkg', 'funk-database' from dual
  7          union select 'funk-database-1.2.nupkg', 'funk-database' from dual
  8          union select 'baz-database-1.0.1.nupkg', 'baz-database' from dual),
  9  temp as
 10    -- remove extension
 11    (select pck pck_old, expected,
 12       replace(lower(pck), '.nupkg', '') pck
 13     from test
 14    )
 15  select pck_old,
 16         expected,
 17    --
 18    nvl(substr(pck, 1, regexp_instr(pck, '\d') - 2), pck) module_name,
 19    --
 20    case when regexp_instr(pck, '\d') = 0 then null
 21         else substr(pck, regexp_instr(pck, '\d'))
 22    end version
 23  from temp;

PCK_OLD                        EXPECTED               MODULE_NAME             VERSION
------------------------------ ---------------------- ----------------------- --------
FOO-BAR-AUDIT-DATABASE.NUPKG   foo-bar-audit-database foo-bar-audit-database
FOO.BAR.DATABASE-2.0.0.NUPKG   foo.bar.database       foo.bar.database        2.0.0
FUNKY_LOG_DATABASE-1.0.0.NUPKG funky_log_database     funky_log_database      1.0.0
baz-database-1.0.1.nupkg       baz-database           baz-database            1.0.1
funk-database-1.2.nupkg        funk-database          funk-database           1.2
funk-database-1.nupkg          funk-database          funk-database           1

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```